# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Category'

Tags: ios, swiftui

This is my first iOS app development project. I'm still learning, everything is new to me. I'me trying here to create three navigation rectangles that navigates to a View from an array. But there are all sorts of error. Here is the Code

```
// ContentView.swiftui

 struct ContentView: View {
    
    struct Category : Identifiable{
        let id = UUID()
        let title: String
    }
    var categories = [
        Category( title: "Menu 1"),
        Category( title: "Menu 2"),
        Category( title: "Menu 3"),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                        ForEach(categories, id:\.title){category in
                            NavigationLink(destination: CategoryView(categories: category.title))
// Here comes the error (Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Category')
                                {
                                ZStack{
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                        .frame(width: 250, height: 120)
                                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                    .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.2), radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
                                    .shadow(color: .white.opacity(0.7), radius: 10, x: -10, y: -10)
                                    Text(category.title)
                                }.padding(5)
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

The next View file is as follows which is also a simple View.

```
// CategoryView.swift

struct CategoryView: View {
    var categories : Category
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(questions){question in
                
                Text("Question \(question.id)")
                
                }
        }
.navigationBarTitle("Welcome") // Also this title is not visible, I've tried changing color.
            .navigationTitle(categories.title)
    }
}
}

struct CategoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        CategoryView(categories: categories[1])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in a string to the initialiser of `CategoryView(categories: category.title)`. Remove the `.title` at the end and pass in the category `CategoryView(categories: category)`.

As for the navigation title, the modifier needs to go inside the `NavigationView` and not attached to the `NavigationView` itself. This is because you can push multiple views onto one NavigationView with different Navigation Bar Titles.

```swift
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(questions) { question in
            Text("Question \(question.id)")
        }
    } // end List
    .navigationBarTitle("Welcome")
} // end NavView
```

Comment: When I try this:
ForEach(categories, id:\.title){category in
                                NavigationLink(destination: CategoryView(categories: category))
a similar error occurs
// error: Cannot convert value of type 'ContentView.Category' to expected argument type 'Category'

Comment: You defined one `Category` struct in `ContentView`, and, presumably, another identical looking `Category` struct elsewhere for all other structs and classes to use. The problem is that the `Category` struct defined in `ContentView`, is not the same thing as a `Category` struct defined elsewhere. The fix should be as simple as removing `Category` struct from `ContentView`.

Comment: I just checked and found another struct of Category. Both of the problems are solved now. Thanks